# scikit-image LineModel() estimate incorrect

Tags: python, scikit-image

I have some pretty straight forward code to segment out a blob and then do a total least squares line fit to it, but the estimate of the line (blue) is clearly not correct.  Anybody know what I did wrong?

[image: segment of dash image under analysis]

```
import skimage as s
import skimage.feature as feat
from skimage import measure
#dash is the original image of the dash as a numpy array
g= dash[2662:2800,3050:3263,0]
edges = feat.canny(g/255., 3.2, .01, .45)
fill = ndimage.binary_fill_holes(edges)
t = s.img_as_ubyte(flt.sobel_h(fill))/2+s.img_as_ubyte(flt.sobel_v(fill))/2
ptpairs = np.int0(np.where(t>160))
l = measure.LineModel()
l.estimate(ptpairs.T)
xdata = np.arange(60,80)
ydata = l.predict_y(xdata)
imshow(g+edges*100)
plot(xdata,ydata)
```

[image: Line Fit Overlay on Gauge Image]

Comment: Can you please provide a) a link to your source image and b) a working code snippet?

Comment: Where can I post an image so that I can provide a link? It's 5.67MB

Comment: could we get an image result from your edgedetection. also, have you tried contouring? OpenCV has a great contouring system that provides a decent least squares line based on the contour points. Basically, is it the points you collect that cause the issue? Maybe there is a gradient that throws off edge detection.

Comment: also have you tried np.int0(np.where(t> # greater than 160))? Still, I tend to use contours to recognize objects and then check colors and what not in a contour bounding box.

Comment: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_contours.html

Comment: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html     (sorry for all the comments its just that this is an alternate way so may not be your preferred solution)

Comment: The Canny results are overlaid on the image provided (white line around the needle).  I'll look into the OpenCV contour function.